# Undefined index:usernames

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I’m trying to pass php variable to another class using ajax to another class known as post.php. It keep saying in another class post.php that “undefined index:usernames” when I try to print it in another class as $echo $nameOfUser can anyone reckon what am I doing wrong? Thanks
index.php

```
<?php
 session_start();
   ?>
  <html>
  <head>
    <script src=“ https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js ”</script>
  </head>

   <body>
    <?php
   global $username;
     $nameOfUser = $_SESSION['name'];
        ?>
        
        <script>
        var username = '<?php echo $nameOfUser ?>';
        console.log(username); //it prints the right username here

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: 'post.php',
            data: {function : 'testing',  usernames: username},
            success: function() {
           alert('success');
            }


        });
        </script>
```

post.php

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 ini_set('display_errors', '1');
  ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
   ?>
  <html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  <hr>
  <?php
   $username = $_POST['usernames'];

   echo $username; // it says here undefined index usernames


   if ($functionname == 0){
    testing($username);
    }

  function testing($username) {
    echo 'my name is: '; //it prints that
   echo $username;   

  }

  ?>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: `type:'POST' != $_GET['usernames']`

Comment: @quentin sorry that was a typo while I was posting my question on SO I do have $_POST instead

Comment: @nigelren yes sorry. I used my phone to post it and while I was changing from GET to POST I made that typo can someone please fix that? In my phone I don’t have that quote

Comment: How do you even see the undefined index error? The JavaScript which makes the request to it doesn't do anything with the response, it just alerts a static string.

Comment: **Danger** jQuery 1.x has been obsolete for **years** and has known security vulnerabilities. Upgrade to a supported version of jQuery.

Comment: @quentin when I print it in another class using echo as I said in my question it prints that there on my website cause I have errors enabled at the top of my php file so it shows all the errors.

Comment: I think, script tag not loaded properly use like this <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @elango I try using script tag like that but it still says the same error unfortunately:(

Comment: @Coder99 I think you did not call the ajax function. when did you calling ajax function. if you want to call default put ajax into one function and call it

Comment: @elango I’m calling the class index.php from another class. Actually this index.php class is named as backend.php. So I have some fields where user enter details and that’s when (index.php but real name backend.php) is called. I have tested by printing it out so the functions are does getting called and I can even see the right values in sources of website (when you press inspect elements) but when I pass values to another class I don’t see any value in sources of inspect class for post.php

Comment: @Coder99 you mean include the index.php file?

Answer (score -1):

`$_POST[...]` reads data from the request.

When you make a POST request to the URL, the data in that request will be available to the PHP handling that URL.

When you make another, separate request, to the URL (or another URL that uses some of the same code) then it will have access to that second request.

It won't have access to the data from the first request.

If you want to persist that data between requests then you need to store it somewhere (such as a session or a database) and retrieve it when you want to use it.

Comment: Did you mean I should store it in database first and then try to fetch from there in same class index.php and pass it to another class using ajax so post.php here?

Answer (score -3):

Your ajax request type is 'POST' and you should use **$_POST** instead of **$_GET**.
Or you can use **$_REQUEST** variable that containt **$_GET**, **$_POST** and **$_COOKIE**.

Comment: Sorry, I’m using _POST that was a typo while posting on SO